# How to debug systemd seccomp SystemCallFilter unit-name.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=31/SYS?

Tags: systemd, sandbox, seccomp

systemd unit file:

```
[Service]
SystemCallFilter=[...]
```

Error message:

> unit-name.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=31/SYS

How to find out which system call is missing in the whitelist?

Answer (score 1):

You can first get the system call that failed with

```
journalctl _AUDIT_TYPE_NAME=SECCOMP
```

Syscall codes (such as syscall=28) are listed in a header under `/usr/include`. For example, on Debian x86_64, it's in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/unistd_64.h`.